# Aws Neptune cache side effect is not working when using next()

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

guys I have started using Aws Neptune to model a service that has multiple many-to-many relationships, I have been trying to build a query that transverses the graph

I found that AWS Neptune is capable of adding cache with side effects so I used that, my question is why when I use the next() function to materialize the results the response time does not decrease despite using cache side-effect, but when I remove the next() function and execute the same query two times the response time is reduced indeed.

This is an example of the query I am running, I have tested this in  Jupyter Notebooks and a Java Application

```java
%%gremlin
g.with("Neptune#enableResultCache", true).V()
 .has("User", "id", "some_id")
 .project("Roles")
    .by(__.union(
            __.out("ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ROLE")
            .has("usage_type",within("1","3","5","7","9","11","13","15"))
            .as("UserRole")
            .out("ASSIGNED_TO_ROLE"),
            __.outE("BELONGS_TO")
            .has("usage_type",within("1","3","5","7","9","11","13","15"))
            .has("deny_user_access","0")
            .inV()
            .out("ASSIGNED_TO_GROUP_ROLE")
            .as("GroupRole")
            .out("ASSIGNED_TO_ROLE")
        )
        .has("system_id", "some_id")
        .dedup()
        .project("Role", "Attributes", "Functional_Abilities")
        .by(__.valueMap("role_name"))
        .by(__.union(
                select("UserRole")
                .out("HAS_USER_ROLE_ATTRIBUTE")
                .has("usage_type",within("1","3","5","7","9","11","13","15"))
                .as("Value")
                .out("HAS_ATTRIBUTE_METADATA")
                .as("Name")
                .out("HAS_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE")
                .as("Type")
                .select("Value", "Name", "Type")
                .by("attribute_value")
                .by("attribute_name")
                .by("attribute_type_name"),
                select("GroupRole")
                .out("HAS_GROUP_ROLE_ATTRIBUTE")
                .has("usage_type",within("1","3","5","7","9","11","13","15"))
                .as("Value")
                .out('HAS_ATTRIBUTE_METADATA')
                .as("Name")
                .out('HAS_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE')
                .as("Type")
                .select("Value", "Name", "Type")
                .by(__.coalesce(__.values("attribute_value"),__.constant('')))
                .by(__.coalesce(__.values("attribute_name"),__.constant('')))
                .by(__.coalesce(__.values("attribute_type_name"),__.constant(''))))
                .dedup()
                .fold()
        )
        .by(
            __.out("ASSIGNED_TO_ROLE_FUNCTIONAL_ABILITY")
                .as("RoleFunctionalAbility")
            .out("ASSIGNED_TO_FUNCTIONAL_ABILITY")
            .project("Functional_Ability", "Attributes", "Secured_Entities")
            .by(__.valueMap("functional_ability_name"))
            .by(
                select("RoleFunctionalAbility")
                .out("HAS_ROLE_FUNCTIONAL_ABILITY_ATTRIBUTES")
                .as("Value")
                .out("HAS_ATTRIBUTE_METADATA")
                .as("Name")
                .out("HAS_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE")
                .as("Type")
                .select("Value", "Name", "Type")
                .by("attribute_value")
                .by("attribute_name")
                .by("attribute_type_name")
                .dedup()
                .fold()
            )
            .by(
                __.out("HAS_SE")
                .valueMap("entity_name","secured_operations")
                .fold()
            )
            .fold()
        )
        .fold()
    )
    .next()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add to the question an example of the two queries you are using (the first to cache a result, and the second to retrieve it)? Also, where are you issuing the queries from - notebook, Gremlin Console, application etc. ?

Comment: Hello thanks for the response I am seeing this issue in the Jupyter notebooks and in the application both when I use the next() function I will update the question with an example of the query

Comment: When you submit the queries from an application, are you submitting them as text strings or as Gremlin ByteCode (using DriverRemoteConnection) - I ask as the `next()` is not needed when sending text queries. The notebooks will submit all queries as text. And just to confirm, your cluster does have the result cache enabled correct? I only ask as it is off by default and needs to be enabled explicitly. Using `%status` in a notebook will show the result cache setting.

Comment: Yeah it has been enabled by the parameter groups,

Comment: Do you have by chance a reference on how can I send the queries as text

Comment: How are you measuring the query latency?  Are you using `%%gremlin profile` or must looking at the Metadata in the notebooks?  The latter is going to show additional time taken by the Jupyter libraries and network latency.  The former will show the actual query latency.

Comment: I'm not sure that using `next()` with Neptune's query cache provides any benefit, as it will not iterate across the results.  It will always pull back the first result in the set of cached results.  Using `range()`, is likely what you're after.  Unless.... all you want is the first result each time.